# How to create a separate custom register form within OpenCart 2?

Tags: php, forms, registration, opencart2.x

I am new to OpenCart 2. By default OpenCart provides the customer registration form uit of the box. I would like to create another registration form for company as user which has different input fields than the customer registration form.

I copied the following files and renamed them properly.

```
- catalog/controller/account/register.php
- catalog/model/account/customer.php
- template/account/register.tpl
```

I have created a new database table for registering companies. When I looked in the `addCustomer($data)` function in the `ModelAccountCustomer` model I stuck with the following line of code.

```
$this->event->trigger('pre.customer.add', $data);
```

I want to change it into `$this->event->trigger('pre.company.add', $data);` in my `addCompany($data)` function of my `ModelAccountCompany` model. But it causes error. How can I solve it?

Another issue is the following line of code inside of my `ControllerAccountRegisterCustomer` controller.

```
$this->customer->isLogged()
and
$this->customer->login();
```

I want to place the similarly code in my `ControllerAccountRegisterCompany` controller as follows.

```
$this->company->isLogged()
and
$this->company->login();
```

But the `$this->company` does not return a company object to call its' functions. How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: Have you created library file of `company `. And created object for that in `index.php` file or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create custom event handler like `$this->event->trigger('pre.company.add', $data);`. First you need to install this event in database. Please check following sample.

```
<?php class ControllerModuleA2bizz extends Controller { 

 public function install() { 
    $this->load->model('extension/event');
    $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('a2bizz', 'pre.admin.store.delete', 'module/a2bizz/on_store_delete');
    $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('a2bizz', 'post.customer.add', 'module/a2bizz/on_customer_add');

 }

public function uninstall() {
    $this->load->model('extension/event');
    $this->model_extension_event->deleteEvent('a2bizz');
}

public function on_store_delete($store_id) {
    $this->load->model('setting/store');
    $store_info = $this->model_setting_store->getStore($store_id);
    $admin_mail = $this->config->get('config_email');
    mail($admin_mail, "A store has been deleted", "The store " . $store_info['url'] . " was deleted.");
 }
}
```

To more about event handler in opencart 2.x. [Read Here](http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/10/24/opencart-2-x-x-event-system-tutorial/)

Comment: I understand your above answer. Your code sample will be executed once the module/extension is installed for the first time. How about when I want to register more events after this module has already been installed? E.g. $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('a2bizz', 'post.customer.newAction', 'module/a2bizz/on_customer_newAction'); Do I need to uninstall the extension and install it again after adding more code to register more events?

Comment: If you want to add more event with uninstall module. You need to add event in **event** table by manual sql query.  Ref: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d85hyc136